# Expand data.table so one row per pattern match of each ID

Tags: r, data.table

I have a lot of text data in a data.table. I have several text patterns that I'm interested in. I have managed to subset the table so it shows text that matches at least two of the patterns (relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655507/)).

I now want to be able to have one row per match, with an additional column that identifies the match - so rows where there are multiple matches will be duplicates apart from that column.

It feels like this shouldn't be too hard but I'm struggling! My vague thoughts are around maybe counting the number of pattern matches, then duplicating the rows that many times...but then I'm not entirely sure how to get the label for each different pattern...(and also not sure that is very efficient anyway).

Thanks for your help!

**Example data**

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
text_table <- data.table(ID = (1:5), 
                         text = c("lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street",
                                  "lucy has only moved here recently",
                                  "lucy and sarah are cousins",
                                  "john is also new to the area",
                                  "paul and john have known each other a long time"))


text_patterns <- as.character(c("lucy", "sarah", "paul|john"))

# Filtering the table to just the IDs with at least two pattern matches
text_table_multiples <- text_table[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(text_patterns, 
                                    function(x) str_detect(text, x))) >1]
```

**Ideal output**

```
required_table <- data.table(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                             text = c("lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street",
                                      "lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street",
                                      "lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street",
                                      "lucy has only moved here recently",
                                      "lucy and sarah are cousins",
                                      "lucy and sarah are cousins",
                                      "john is also new to the area",
                                      "paul and john have known each other a long time"), 
                             person = c("lucy", "sarah", "paul or john", "lucy", "lucy", "sarah", "paul or john", "paul or john"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do that is to create a variable for each indicator and melt:

```r
library(stringi)
text_table[, lucy := stri_detect_regex(text, 'lucy')][ ,
  sarah := stri_detect_regex(text, 'sarah')
][ ,`paul or john` := stri_detect_regex(text, 'paul|john')
]

melt(text_table, id.vars = c("ID", "text"))[value == T][, -"value"]
##    ID                                            text     variable
## 1:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street         lucy
## 2:  2               lucy has only moved here recently         lucy
## 3:  3                      lucy and sarah are cousins         lucy
## 4:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street        sarah
## 5:  3                      lucy and sarah are cousins        sarah
## 6:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street paul or john
## 7:  4                    john is also new to the area paul or john
## 8:  5 paul and john have known each other a long time paul or john
```

A tidy way of doing the same procedure is:

```r
library(tidyverse)
text_table %>%
  mutate(lucy = stri_detect_regex(text, 'lucy')) %>%
  mutate(sarah = stri_detect_regex(text, 'sarah')) %>%
  mutate(`paul or john` = stri_detect_regex(text, 'paul|john')) %>%
  gather(value = value, key = person,  - c(ID, text)) %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  select(-value)
```

Comment: It looks like this works, thanks! I think this is roughly what I was imagining doing but I was struggling to get through the individual steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: this is not an idiomatic `data.table` solution

I would build a helper function like the following, that take a single row and an input and returns a new dt with Nrows:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

new_rows <- function(dtRow, patterns = text_patterns){

    res <- map(text_patterns, function(word) {

        textField <- grep(x = dtRow[1, text], pattern = word, value = TRUE) %>% 
            ifelse(is.character(.), ., NA)

        personField   <- str_extract(string = dtRow[1, text], pattern = word) %>% 
            ifelse(  . == "paul" | . == "john", "paul or john", .)

        idField <- ifelse(is.na(textField), NA, dtRow[1, ID])

        data.table(ID = idField, text = textField, person = personField) 

        }) %>% 
        rbindlist()

    res[!is.na(text), ]
}
```

And I will execute it:

```
split(text_table, f = text_table[['ID']]) %>% 
    map_df(function(r) new_rows(dtRow = r))
```

The answer is:

```
   ID                                            text       person
1:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street         lucy
2:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street        sarah
3:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street paul or john
4:  2               lucy has only moved here recently         lucy
5:  3                      lucy and sarah are cousins         lucy
6:  3                      lucy and sarah are cousins        sarah
7:  4                    john is also new to the area paul or john
8:  5 paul and john have known each other a long time paul or john
```

which looks like your `required_table` (duplicated IDs included)

```
   ID                                            text       person
1:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street         lucy
2:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street        sarah
3:  1    lucy, sarah and paul live on the same street paul or john
4:  2               lucy has only moved here recently         lucy
5:  3                      lucy and sarah are cousins         lucy
6:  3                      lucy and sarah are cousins        sarah
7:  4                    john is also new to the area paul or john
8:  5 paul and john have known each other a long time paul or john
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at this yet but I will soon and compare to the answer above :)